# Difference between std::mutex lock function and std::lock_guard<std::mutex>?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mutex, objective-c++

Basically, the title is self-explanatory.
I use it in following way:

- The code is in Objective-C++.
- Objective-C classes make concurrent calls to different purpose functions.
- I use `std::mutex` to `lock` and `unlock` `std::vector<T>` editing option across entire class, as C++ std containers are not thread safe.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using `lock_guard` automatically unlocks the mutex again when it goes out of scope. That makes it impossible to forget to unlock it, when returning, or when an exception is thrown. You should **always** prefer to use `lock_guard` or `unique_lock` instead of using `mutex::lock()`. See http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#locking-mutex

`lock_guard` is an example of an [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) or [SBRM](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) type.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::lock_guard` is only used for two purposes:

1. Automate mutex unlock during destruction (no need to call `.unlock()`).
2. Allow simultaneous lock of multiple mutexes to overcome deadlock problem.

For the last use case you will need `std::adopt_lock` flag:

```
std::lock(mutex_one, mutex_two);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockPurposeOne(mutex_one, std::adopt_lock);
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockPurposeTwo(mutex_two, std::adopt_lock);
```

On the other hand, you will need allocate yet another class instance for the guard every time you need to lock the mutex, as `std::lock_guard` has no member functions. If you need guard with unlocking functionality take a look at `std::unique_lock` class. You may also consider using `std::shared_lock` for parallel reading of your vector.

You may notice, that `std::shared_lock` class is commented in header files and will be only accessible with C++17. According to header file you can use `std::shared_timed_mutex`, but when you will try to build the app it will fail, as Apple had updated the header files, but not the libc++  itself.

So for Objective-C app it may be more convenient to use GCD, allocate a couple of queue for all your C++ containers at the same time and put semaphores where needed. Take a look at this excellent [comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8681747/2766161).

Comment: What does _"you will need allocate yet another class instance for the guard every time you need to lock the mutex"_ mean? You make it sound like `lock_guard` is bad.

Comment: Its not bad if you need it. But if you build the app in the way, that deadlock will not be possible - you don't need it.